# how to convert string to date (HHMMMDD) (hour, month, day-of-month)

Tags: java, string, date, datetime, converters

I try to convert a string into date type. This is the whole what I did.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHMMMDD");

String date = "23Mar25";

System.out.println(date);

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

System.out.println(localDate);
```

And I got the error information as

```
Text '23Mar25' could not be parsed: 
Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 
{MonthOfYear=3, DayOfYear=25},ISO resolved to 23:00 of type 
java.time.format.Parsed at 
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
```

Anyone can help me to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that input string means hour, month, and day-of-month? No year?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse( "23Mar25" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "HHMMMdd", Locale.US )
         .toString()  // 23:00
```

…and…

```
MonthDay.parse( "23Mar25" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "HHMMMdd", Locale.US )
        .toString()   // --03-25
```

## Details

If you are certain that input indeed represents an hour-of-day, month, and day-of-month…

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a single `DateTimeFormatter`. Be sure to specify a `Locale` for the human language by which to translate the abbreviated name of the month.

```
String input = "23Mar25";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "HHMMMdd", Locale.US );
```

### `LocalTime`

Use that formatter twice. Once to produce a time-of-day as a `LocalTime` object to hold the hour-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse ( input, f );
```

### `MonthDay`

Again to produce a [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) object to hold the month and the day-of-month.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse ( input , f  );
```

### `ZoneId`

To make a specific moment of that value, we must assign a year and a time zone. If we want to use use the current year, we need a time zone for that as well. Keep in mind the fact that for any given moment both the date and the time-of-day vary around the globe by zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
```

### `LocalDate`

Determine a `LocalDate` object by assigning a year to our `MonthDay` object.

```
int yearNumber = Year.now ( z )
                     .getValue ( ) ;
LocalDate ld = md.atYear ( yearNumber );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Combine with the `LocalTime` to get an exact moment, a point on the timeline. Result is a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of ( ld, lt, z );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "lt: " + lt );
System.out.println ( "md: " + md );
System.out.println ( "ld: " + ld );
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt );
```

> input: 23Mar25
>
> lt: 23:00
>
> md: --03-25
>
> ld: 2017-03-25
>
> zdt: 2017-03-25T23:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

### `OffsetDateTime`

If your input is intended for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then instead of `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, use [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) constant and [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class in code similar to above.

```
OffsetDateTime zdt = OffsetDateTime.of ( ld, lt, ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

### ISO 8601

Notice the output, the strings generated by the `toString` methods. The java.time classes use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. I strongly suggest you and your data-source use these standard formats rather than invent your own such as seen in the Question. The java.time classes can directly parse as well as generate such standard strings without needing to specify a formatting pattern.

To generate strings in other formats, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. That topic is covered by many other Stack Overflow pages, so search for many examples and more discussion.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I need! Thanks a lot! But here still a little problem, any method I can do to get the output like: "23:00 Mar 25"?

Comment: @WenjieJia I added more to show specifying a year and time zone to get an exact moment.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really useful! I got it, awesome!

Comment: @WenjieJia Please answer the Comment I left earlier on your Question. Edit your Question to make it absolutely clear that yes indeed the incoming string represents an hour-of-day, name-of-month, and day-of-month but no year. Yours is an unusual and confusing format.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHMMMDD");
```

It is using a pattern for:

```
HH: 2 spaces for hour
MMM: 3 spaces for month
DD: 2 spaces for day
```

I think you want a format like: `ddmmmyy

```
dd: 2 spaces for day
mmm: 3 spaces for month
yy: 2 spaces for year
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need the output to be "23 Mar 25", hour + Month + Date, any method I can do?

Comment: 'DD' id for day of year. I suppose you want the day of month which is 'dd'.Suppose you refer http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html